# How to turn an array of words into an array containing the characters of the words in order?

Tags: string, perl

I have an array of unknown number of words, with an unknown max length.
I need to convert it to another array, basically turning it into a column word array.
so with this original array:

```
@original_array = ("first", "base", "Thelongest12", "justAWORD4");
```

The resluting array would be:

```
@result_array = ("fbTj","iahu","rses","selt","t oA","  nW","  gO","  eR","  sD","  t4","  1 ","  2 ");
```

Actually I will have this:

```
fbTj
iahu
rses
selt
t oA
  nW
  gO
  eR
  sD
  t4
  1
  2
```

I need to do it in order to make a table, and these words are the table's headers.
I hope I have made myself clear, and appreciate the help you are willing to give.

I tried it with the split function, but I keep messing it up...

EDIT:
Hi all, thanks for all the tips and suggestions! I learned quite much from all of you hence the upvote. However I found tchrist's answer more convenient, maybe because I come from a c,c# background... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have an old program that does this.  Maybe you can adapt it:

```
$ cat /tmp/a
first
base
Thelongest12
justAWORD4

$ rot90 /tmp/a
fbTj
iahu
rses
selt
t oA
  nW
  gO
  eR
  sD
  t4
  1 
  2
```

Here’s the source:

```
$ cat ~/scripts/rot90
#!/usr/bin/perl 
# rot90 - tchrist@perl.com

$/ = '';

# uncomment for easier to read, but not reversible:
### @ARGV = map { "fmt -20 $_ |" } @ARGV;

while ( <> ) {
    chomp;
    @lines = split /\n/;
    $MAXCOLS = -1;
    for (@lines) { $MAXCOLS = length if $MAXCOLS < length; }
    @vlines = ( " " x @lines ) x $MAXCOLS;
    for ( $row = 0; $row < @lines; $row++ ) {
        for ( $col = 0; $col < $MAXCOLS; $col++ ) {
            $char = ( length($lines[$row]) > $col  )
                    ? substr($lines[$row], $col, 1) 
                    : ' ';
            substr($vlines[$col], $row, 1) = $char;
        }
    }
    for (@vlines) {
        # uncomment for easier to read, but again not reversible
        ### s/(.)/$1 /g;
        print $_, "\n";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use Algorithm::Loops 'MapCarU';

my @original_array = ("first", "base", "Thelongest12", "justAWORD4");
my @result_array = MapCarU { join '', map $_//' ', @_ } map [split //], @original_array;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw(max);

my @original_array = ("first", "base", "Thelongest12", "justAWORD4");
my @new_array = transpose(@original_array);

sub transpose {
    my @a = map { [ split // ] } @_;
    my $max = max(map $#$_, @a);
    my @out;
    for my $n (0 .. $max) {
        $out[$n] .= defined $a[$_][$n] ? $a[$_][$n] : ' ' for 0 .. $#a;
    }
    return @out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done easily by this simple one-liner:

```
perl -le'@l=map{chomp;$m=length if$m<length;$_}<>;for$i(0..$m-1){print map substr($_,$i,1)||" ",@l}'
```